# Need the image to be in the same position in both divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

I need the image in the both divs below to be in the same position even if the other div changes height or width. I have tried calculating top and left to % from px but still it is not working. I have also tried calculating the % of how big or small other div is and adding or removing the top and left to the image in other div and still no luck.

To check the issue, drag the image around inside the first div and click on submit. Now the image inside the bottom div should be in the same position as the above div, same top and left distance.

Please help. Thanks.

Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kashyap_s/gLdt62nh

```js
var zoomLevel = 1;

$("#myimage").draggable({
  start: function() {
  },
  stop: function() {
  }
});

$('#save').click(function() {
  var topcss = $('#myimage').css('top');
  var leftcss = $('#myimage').css('left');
  var transformcss = zoomLevel;

  topcss = topcss.replace('px', '');
  leftcss = leftcss.replace('px', '');
  topcss = parseInt(topcss);
  leftcss = parseInt(leftcss);
  var parentWidth = $('#dragDiv').outerWidth()
  var parentHeight = $('#dragDiv').outerHeight()
  console.log('leftcss', leftcss, 'width', parentWidth)
  console.log('topcss', topcss, 'height', parentHeight)
  var percentLeft = leftcss / parentWidth * 100;
  var percentTop = topcss / parentHeight * 100;
  console.log('percentLeft', percentLeft, 'percentTop', percentTop)

  transformcss = parseFloat(transformcss).toFixed(2);
  var result = {
    "top": topcss,
    "left": leftcss,
    'percentTop': percentTop,
    'percentLeft': percentLeft,
    'parentWidth': parentWidth,
    'parentHeight': parentHeight,
    "transform": "scale(" + transformcss + ")"
  };
  var output = JSON.stringify(result);
  console.log('output', output)
  $("#newimg").css({
    'left': leftcss
  });
  $("#newimg").css({
    'top': topcss
  });
});
```

```css
.transperentimage {
  width: 497px;
  height: 329px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#bigimg {
  width: 651px;
  height: 431px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 3px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  cursor: move;
  max-height: 180px;
}

#newimg {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 180px;
  width: auto!important;
  height: auto!important;
  max-width: 100%!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="transperentimage" id="dragDiv">
  <img id="myimage" src="agent.png">
</div>
<button id="save">Save</button>

<div id="bigimg">
  <img id="newimg" src="agent.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your snippet to use an image service like https://dummyimage.com/ so that the images are not broken. Also, please explain any steps needed to reproduce the problem in the code given. Remove any irrelevant code (like references to `draggable`) if they are not needed.

Comment: I have updated the code and added description how to check the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {

  $("#logo1").draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    drag: function() {


    }
  });
});


function setpos() {
  var image1_w = $("#logo1").width();
  var div1_w = $(".div1").width();
  var image2_w = $("#logo2").width();
  var div2_w = $(".div2").width();
  var image1_h = $("#logo1").height();
  var div1_h = $(".div1").height();
  var image2_h = $("#logo2").height();
  var div2_h = $(".div2").height();



  var div1_aw = div1_w - image1_w;
  var div2_aw = div2_w - image2_w;
  var div1_ah = div1_h - image1_h;
  var div2_ah = div2_h - image2_h;


  var div

  var xPos = $('#logo1').css('left');
  var yPos = $('#logo1').css('top');
  var ratio_w = parseFloat(div1_aw) / parseFloat(div2_aw);
  var ratio_h = parseFloat(div1_ah) / parseFloat(div2_ah);
  //let act = 1.39;



  var div2_nw = parseFloat(xPos) / ratio_w;
  var div2_nh = parseFloat(yPos) / ratio_h;
  $("#posX").text('Div left:' + div2_nw);
  $("#posA").text('Div Top:' + div2_nh);
  $("#logo2").css({
    'left': div2_nw,
    'top': div2_nh
  });
}
```

```css
.div1 {
  width: 497px;
  height: 329px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div2 {
  width: 651px;
  height: 431px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<p>Drag my logo.</p>




<div class="div1">
  <img src="https://smteg.sefion.com/perfectmetal/assets/ui/sefion.jpg" style=" position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" width="100" id="logo1">
</div>
<br>
<div class="div2">
  <img style="position: relative;left: 0px;top: 0px" src="https://smteg.sefion.com/perfectmetal/assets/ui/sefion.jpg" width="100" id="logo2">
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="setpos();">
Save
</button>
<div id="posX">

</div>
<div id="posA">

</div>

<div id="posz">

</div>
<div id="posZ1">

</div>
```

Solved! check this out

***HTML***

```
  <p>Drag my logo.</p>

<div class="div1">
<img src="https://smteg.sefion.com/perfectmetal/assets/ui/sefion.jpg" style=" position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" width="100"  id="logo1">
</div>
<br>
<div class="div2">
<img style="position: relative;left: 0px;top: 0px" src="https://smteg.sefion.com/perfectmetal/assets/ui/sefion.jpg"  width="100"  id="logo2">
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="setpos();">
Save
</button>
<div id="posX"></div>
<div id="posA"></div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
 $( function() {
  
    $( "#logo1" ).draggable(
    {
      containment: "parent",
     drag: function() {
        
       
    }
    }
    );
  } );
  
  
  function setpos()
  {
   var image1_w = $("#logo1").width();
        var div1_w = $(".div1").width();
        var image2_w = $("#logo2").width();
        var div2_w = $(".div2").width();
         var image1_h = $("#logo1").height();
        var div1_h = $(".div1").height();
        var image2_h = $("#logo2").height();
        var div2_h = $(".div2").height();
        
        
        
        var div1_aw = div1_w-image1_w;
        var div2_aw = div2_w-image2_w;
        var div1_ah = div1_h-image1_h;
        var div2_ah = div2_h-image2_h;
        
        
        var div
        
        var xPos = $('#logo1').css('left');
        var yPos = $('#logo1').css('top');
            var ratio_w = parseFloat(div1_aw)/parseFloat(div2_aw);
      var ratio_h = parseFloat(div1_ah)/parseFloat(div2_ah);
          //let act = 1.39;
          
          
          
          var div2_nw = parseFloat(xPos)/ratio_w;
           var div2_nh = parseFloat(yPos)/ratio_h;
                 $("#posX").text('Div left:' + div2_nw);
         $("#posA").text('Div Top:' + div2_nh);
        $("#logo2").css({ 'left' : div2_nw, 'top' : div2_nh});
  }
```

**CSS**

```
.div1{
  width: 497px;
  height: 329px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.div2{
  width: 651px;
  height: 431px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your `newimg`, the parent must have a `position` that is `relative`. This way, the `absolute` positioning will be relative to the parent and not the `body`.

> An element with `position: absolute;` is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  var zoomLevel = parseFloat(1 - ($("#dragDiv").outerWidth() / $("#bigimg").outerWidth()).toFixed(2));

  function log(str) {
    if ($(".log").length) {
      $(".log").html(str);
    } else {
      $("<div>", {
        class: "log"
      }).html(str).appendTo("body");
    }
  }

  function getPos(el) {
    var par = $(el).parent();
    var pos = {
      top: parseInt($(el).css("top")),
      left: parseInt($(el).css("left")),
      zoom: "scale(" + (1 + zoomLevel) + ")",
      parWidth: par.outerWidth(),
      parHeight: par.outerHeight()
    };
    pos['perLeft'] = parseFloat((pos.left / pos.parWidth).toFixed(2)) * 100;
    pos['perTop'] = parseFloat((pos.top / pos.parHeight).toFixed(2)) * 100;

    return pos;
  }

  $("#myimage").draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      log("Left: " + ui.position.left + ", Top: " + ui.position.top);
    },
    start: function() {
      // coordinates('#myimage');
    },
    stop: function() {
      // coordinates('#myimage');
      var p = getPos(this);
      $(this).attr("title", JSON.stringify(p));
    }
  });

  $('#save').click(function() {
    var result = getPos($("#myimage"));
    var output = JSON.stringify(result);
    var nLeft = Math.round(result.perLeft * (1 + zoomLevel)) + "%";
    var nTop = Math.round(result.perTop * (1 + zoomLevel)) + "%"
    console.log(output, nLeft, nTop);
    $("#newimg").css({
      left: nLeft,
      top: nTop
    });
    var p = getPos($("#newimg"));
    $("#newimg").attr("title", JSON.stringify(p));
  });
});
```

```css
.transperentimage {
  width: 497px;
  height: 329px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#bigimg {
  width: 651px;
  height: 431px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 3px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  cursor: move;
  /* max-width: 100%; */
  max-height: 180px;
}

#newimg {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 180px;
  width: auto!important;
  height: auto!important;
  max-width: 100%!important;
}

.log {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="transperentimage" id="dragDiv">
  <img id="myimage" src="https://i.imgur.com/4ILisqH.jpg">
</div>
<button id="save">Save</button>

<div id="bigimg">
  <img id="newimg" src="https://i.imgur.com/4ILisqH.jpg" />
</div>
```

See More: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

**Updated**

Looking at it further, I am guessing that you might be trying to reposition the `bigimg` in relationship to `myimage` position. This requires scaling the percentage.

For example, if we move `myimage` to the far left, it will be at `left: 247`, and this is roughly 49% of 499px. 49% of 653 is around 319, and this would not place the image where we want it. We want it at 401.

`bigimg` is about 24% larger than `dragDiv`, so we need to scale our percentage. `49 * 1.24 = 60.74`, round up to 61. `653 * .61 = 398.33` so better yet not perfect.

Comment: The position works, but the image is not in the same position as above div. I have updated the description above on what is the problem. Thanks.

Comment: can you please explain the above calculation?

Comment: This works for getting left but not for getting top position

Comment: @dev_sk this works for both `top` and `left` assuming that both are the same ratio relationship. If not, you should calculate a Zoom Ratio for `top` in addition to `left`

Comment: I have created a fiddle from above calculations but the top is not correct and when you put the image in the top div to bottom right corner the image gets out of the div for the bottom div. Please check the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/kashyap_s/qxe36jos/2/

Comment: I am bad with Ratios so I cobbled this together: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/qkx04nhL/31/